# How to find radio button value and ID with xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, angular, automated-testing

```
<rhr-radio-button element-id="tenderValidType" model="$ctrl.additionalData.procProcedure.tenderValidType" value="UNTIL_DATE" label="additionalData.tenderValidUntil" required="::$ctrl.requiredFields['tenderValidType']" read-only="$ctrl.isReadOnly" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
   <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.horizontal !== 'true' && !$ctrl.readOnly -->
   <div class="radio ng-scope" ng-if="$ctrl.horizontal !== 'true' &amp;&amp; !$ctrl.readOnly">
      <label>
         <input type="radio" class="px ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" name="tenderValidType" ng-value="::$ctrl.value" ng-model="$ctrl.model" ng-required="$ctrl.innerRequired" ng-disabled="$ctrl.disabled" ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()" value="UNTIL_DATE" required="required"> <span class="lbl ng-binding" ng-bind="::($ctrl.label | translate) + '&nbsp;'">Pakkumus peab olema jõus kuni&nbsp;</span><!-- ngIf: $ctrl.showHelpText === 'true' -->
      </label>
   </div>
   <!-- end ngIf: $ctrl.horizontal !== 'true' && !$ctrl.readOnly --><!-- ngIf: $ctrl.horizontal === 'true' && !$ctrl.readOnly --><!-- ngIf: $ctrl.readOnly && $ctrl.value == $ctrl.model -->
</rhr-radio-button>
```

I've tried everything here, like this:

```
 await element(by.xpath((//label[contains(@for,'rhr-radio-button')])[1])).click();
```

and this

```
await element(by.id('tenderValidType')).all(by.tagName('rhr-radio-button')).get(1).click();
```

But nothing.. I think I should combine the ID and the value into one xpath, but I don't know how. Any ideas?

Comment: try this  `//input[@type='radio']//id[@name='tenderValidType']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to suggest things without being able to test or check them, but, according to the information we have and taking into account that there could be multiple `rhr-radio-button` elements on a page, I'd combine the tag name check and the `element-id` check:

```
$('rhr-radio-button[element-id=tenderValidType]').click();
```

Note that `element-id` attribute could not be targeted with the `by.id()` locator as `by.id()` looks for `id` attributes.

One other option, you may try to look for the `input` element directly:

```
$('input[name=tenderValidType]').click();
```

Note: `$('...')` here is a shortcut to `element(by.css('...'))`.